# How to write conditional command (if...then) in package depending on document class option?

Tags: packages, memoir, conditionals

I'm new and this is my very first post. I searched the site and couldn't find the answer to my question. If there's a duplicate question that I didn't find, please let me know.

I have a template using `memoir` class and the most used option is `a4paper` or `letterpaper` depending on to whom I send the document.

I have a tufte-like style file defining different margins for `a4paper` or `letterpaper`.

```
\ProvidesPackage{memtufte}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{%
  \settrims{0pt}{0pt}%
  \settypeblocksize{640pt}{310pt}{*}%
  \setlrmargins{63.754pt}{*}{*}%
  \setmarginnotes{16pt}{144pt}{0.7\baselineskip}%
}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{%
  \settrims{0pt}{0pt}%
  \settypeblocksize{600pt}{320pt}{*}%
  \setlrmargins{64.1475pt}{*}{*}%
  \setmarginnotes{16pt}{150pt}{0.5\baselineskip}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
... ... (and some other settings that are common for a4paper and letterpaper.
```

and in `main.tex` file I write something like the following,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,article,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{memtufte}
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,article,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[a4paper]{memtufte}
```

This works; but I have to change both class and package options to keep them the same.

1. So my first question is how I can re-write the package in such a way that I can simply use `\usepackage{memtufte}` in main file and margin will be set correctly according to class option.
2. Second question is if this can be generalized to any class options (A, B, C, ...) e.g.,

   ```
   if class option is A, then do something, 
   if class option is B and C, do something else,
   if class option is C, do another thing,
   ...
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\ProcessOptions` also reads the global options (the options set in `\documentclass`). Thus,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{memtufte}
```

also triggers the option handling for `a4paper` in `memtufte`.
This can easily be verified by adding `\typeout{}` calls in the option code, e.g.:

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{%
  ...%
  \typeout{memtufte:a4paper}%
}
```

Then the console and `.log` file contains the line

```
memtufte:a4paper
```

### Second question

Usually global options (options specified in `\documentclass`) are passed to the package. Thus, the package can read them via the normal `\DeclareOption`:

```
\DeclareOption{A}{... do something ...}
\ProcessOptions\relax % or \ProcessOptions*
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I forgot to change package option the same as the class option and I would get error message. I always thought I need to write package option explicitly so I didn't even thought about using the package without option. You're right. It works fine as you said. Before I accept your answer, could you answer my second question about if I can generalize it (maybe for different class) and use something like if / then to program conditionally depending on the certain, or **combinations of**, class options?